# Xamarin android Manifest being replaced on build. only solution seems to be to repair visual studio

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Im not really sure how to being this... this started a couple months ago every so often i would receive apk install failed errors and when i unzipped my built apk and looked at the android manifest mine was replaced with a android manifest from a sample serial port library i was testing with a while back. This problem has become constant to the point where every 3 builds or so i have to use the visual studio installer to repair visual studio. Cleaning the solution doesn't fix it nor does deleting my local visual studio files or bin/obj folders. I have cloned my solution over to my personal desktop and it built fine and has never exhibited these problems so i believe its environment specific. if anyone has run into a similar problem or has any suggestions i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I am going to attempt a full uninstall and reinstall of visual studio today. i will update this post if it helps at all.

Comment: A Full uninstall and reinstall later and the problem poped up after 1 build... im going to do a quick repair then attempt a new device perhaps its something its pulling off the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! the newest non preview xamarin android will do this if you have a bound jar . here is a link to the github issue this should be fixed in future versions for now im updating to the preview visual studio.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4804

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT
I cant until tomorrow but i will once it is available.

Answer (score 0):

With Xamarin.Android some of the AndroidManifest.xml file is generated at build time.

All types which have `[Application]`, `[Activity]` or `[Service]` attributes and their extra stuff like `[IntentFilter]`, `[MetaData]` will be added to the manifest at build time.

You can verify this by comparing `Properties/AndroidManifest.xml` to the one generated which usually can be found in the `obj/Debug/Android` folder. You should see that your Activities are added there.

If you use the [`Xamarin.Android.ManifestMerger`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.ManifestMerger) package, additional content from Android Libraries might be added to the manifest as well

Comment: That sounds really strange. Check your csproj file, maybe you have accidentally linked the AndroidManifest from that project somehow and it is overriding the one in your App

Comment: Sorry for the earleir message i was looking at the wrong file.
This is actually quite interesting when i do a build and deploy the generated android manifest matches the serial port library exactly however the android manifest inside of obj/debug/android matches my application and seems to be correct. im going to start looking into where its getting changed betwean generation and deployment.