# AndroidManifest.xml merger failing, cached intermediate file Visual Studio Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

Strange problem with Manifest Merger, Visual Studio Mac, Xamarin Forms (5.0.0.2125), Android project, SDK 29 to 30.  Problem initiated from an extra ">" in the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml file.  That generated the error below, indicating the xml structure wasn't closed; line 35, column 11 being was the last line and character of the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error AMM0000: Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 11; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (AMM0000)

So, I edited out the extra character, and the obj/debug/AndroidManifest.xml is created and looks right, however, the build error remains the same!

Subsequent complete rewrites and edits of the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml file have only 2 outcomes

1. Entering an erroneous xml format will generate the appropriate errors describing the error.
2. Entering a correct xml format, with any combination of entries, lines and characters will generate a correct obj/debug/AndroidManifest.xml file with the the correct Properties/AndroidManifest.xml content.  However, the original build errors stay, with the " line 35, column 11 being was the last line and character of the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml." error.

So, something cached, somewhere, but no clue where. Started during an aborted simulator build and has been here ever since.

Have tried quite few things including:

- cleaning, rebuilding and many combinations
- remove obj and bin
- removing/adding declarations in the AndroidManifest.xml
- using different AndroidManifest.xml files
- deleting AndroidManifest.xml and running
- restoring from cloud a different version of solutions
- commenting out Activity declaration on MainActivity
- reinstall of VS for Mac

I think it is similar to this bug
[Xamarin android Manifest being replaced on build. only solution seems to be to repair visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116064/xamarin-android-manifest-being-replaced-on-build-only-solution-seems-to-be-to-r)

Has anyone seen this type of bug before?
Help much appreciated as have run out of ideas here.

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="17" android:versionName="1.17" package="com.mycompany.myapp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="myapp" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code of  `AndroidManifest.xml` in your `obj\Debug` folder of your android project?

Comment: What you don't understand by `Problem initiated from an extra ">" in the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Hello Jessie, have added this information here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6385  Problem still exists, am trying to find if there is an equivalent manifest merge view in VS mac similar to the Android Studio function https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests

Comment: Hello Martin, I understand that an extra character may have (I say may, but I am not 100% sure) initiated the manifest errors.  But then after correcting the syntax, the manifest errors remain, exactly the same.  And now despite combinations of altering the Properties/AndroidManifest.xml, removing, replacing, renaming, de bugging, reinstalling, regression to older buildable versions of the entire solution, etc. etc  The build errors remain.

Comment: Solved here, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6385.  Was a problem in a Nuget Firebase library AndroidManifest.xml file.  Unfortunately the error reporting in VS Mac Manifest merging doesn't report which of the 140+ AndroidManifest.xml files has the problem.  However, with a bit of sleuthing, there is a way to eventually work it out.

Answer (score -1):

Solved here, github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6385. Was a problem in a Nuget Firebase library AndroidManifest.xml file. Unfortunately the error reporting in VS Mac Manifest merging doesn't report which of the 140+ AndroidManifest.xml files has the problem. However, with a bit of sleuthing, there is a way to eventually work it out.